# javascript minimax algorithm tic tac toe, not always giving the best move

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have been trying to use minimax algorithm for my tic tac toe game to make my AI unbeatable. However it doesn't always return the optimal move.

```
AI = X; human = "O"

var board =  ["x", "x", "-",
               "-", "o", "o",
               "-", "-", "-"]
```

It gives the board above index[2] as the optimal move which is correct.

However, with the board below, the answer it gives is index[3], which will allow the human player to win on its turn.

```
var boardB = ["x","x","o",
             "-","o","-",
             "-","_","-"];

var player = 'x';
var opponent = 'o';

function isMovesLeft(board){
    for (var i = 0; i<board.length; i++){
        if (board[i] =='-'){
            return 'true';
        }
        else{
            return 'false';
        }
    }
}



function evaluate(){
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i += 3) {
        if (board[i] === board[i + 1] && board[i + 1] === board[i + 2]) {
            if (board[i] == player){
                return +10;  
            }
            else if(board[i]== opponent){
                return -10;
            } 
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        if (board[j] === board[j + 3] && board[j + 3] === board[j + 6]) {
            if (board[j] == player){
                return +10;  
            }
            else if(board[j] == opponent){
                return -10;
            } 
        }
    }


  if ((board[4]==board[0] && board[4]==board[8]) || (board[4]==board[2] && board[4]==board[6])) {
    if (board[4]==player){
        return +10;
    }
    else if (board[4]==opponent){
        return -10;
    }
 }

return 0;
}



function minimax(board, depth, isMax){
    var score = evaluate(board);

    if (score == 10){
        return score;
    }

    if (score == -10){
        return score;
    }

    if (isMovesLeft(board) =="false"){
        return 0;
    }

    if (isMax == "true"){
        var best = -1000;

        for (var i = 0; i< board.length; i++){
            if (board[i]=='-'){
                board.splice(i, 1, player);
                var value = minimax(board, depth+1, "false");
                best = Math.max(best, value);

                board.splice(i, 1, "-");
            }
         }
         return best;  
     }

    else if (isMax == 'false'){
        var best = 1000;
        for (var i = 0; i<board.length; i++){
            if (board[i]=='-'){
             board.splice(i, 1, opponent);
             var value = minimax(board, depth+1, "true");
             best = Math.min(best, value);

             board.splice(i, 1, "-");
            }
         }
        return best;
      }
}

function findBestMove(board){
    var bestVal = -1000;
    var bestMove= -1;

    for (var i = 0; i<board.length; i++){
        if (board[i]=='-'){
            board.splice(i, 1, player);
            var moveVal = minimax(board, 0, "false");

            board.splice(i, 1, "-");

            if (moveVal > bestVal)
            {
                bestMove = i;
                bestVal = moveVal;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("bestVal is : " + bestVal + "<br> best Move is : " + bestMove;)
}
```

I wonder what is wrong with my code. Below are some websites that I used as references:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-3-tic-tac-toe-ai-finding-optimal-move/

https://blog.vivekpanyam.com/how-to-build-an-ai-that-wins-the-basics-of-minimax-search/

But I still can't figure out the reason why it's not always returning the optimal move.
I hope someone can lead me to the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the `moveVal` for each `i` you'll see that it's zero.
That's because in the minimax function you call `isMovesLeft` which when false returns 0.
The problem with your program is that `isMovesLeft` always returns `false`.
You should change it to :

```
function isMovesLeft(board){
    for (var i = 0; i<board.length; i++){
        if (board[i] =='-'){
            return 'true';
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

This change should have your program get 6 as the best move.

The parameter `depth` is never used anywhere.
You can use it while returning the score: `return score/depth`
This will ensure that the short term consequences of losing/winning have more effect than long term.

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh! It worked for the boards above. However, if i change the board again to different order such that AI should block human player's move to prevent the human player from winning. The answer for the board below is index[3].`var board = ["x","o","x",
                                                                  "-","o","-",
                                                                  "-","_","-"];`
 I think the minimax function just gives the index with lowest number, in this case [3], when it encounters a bestscore of 0.

Comment: @Marci Banez I tried that board, it probably didn't work with you because at the index 7 you've got '_'(underscore) instead of '-'(hyphen). If you change the `isMovesLeft` function to what I mentioned in my answer, then you should get `bestMove` as 7 which effectively blocks `0` from winning.

Comment: You are right!! Thanks a lot! I missed a lot of things in this code. Everything works fine now. However, you mentioned earlier that i can return the `depth` together with the score. I wonder how do i implement that and I am also not so sure how it will improve the AI to be more effective.